# SQL Server : get only numers from value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like this

```
Column 1
-----------------
pink dog 306
black friday 225
red potato 809
```

and I would like get an output like this

```
Column 1                      column2
--------------------------------------                   
pink dog 306                  306
black friday 225              225
red potato 809                809
```

I am using this script

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TAble]
SET column2 = RIGHT([Column1], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE([Column1])) -1)
```

And do not know why I get this error

> Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: are the numbers always on the end in that format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `patindex` like this:

```
select 
    *, 
    substring([Column 1], patindex('%[0-9]%',[Column 1]), 5)
from 
    t;
```

```
update  t
set 
    [Column 1] = substring([Column 1], patindex('%[0-9]%',[Column 1]), 5)
where 
    patindex('%[0-9]%', [Column 1]) > 0;  --to filter records those have number inside Column 1
```

---

A more reliable way to detect last number of a string will be something like this:

```
reverse(
    substring(
        reverse([Column 1]), 
        patindex('%[0-9]%', reverse([Column 1])), 
        patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(
                                 reverse([Column 1]), 
                                 patindex('%[0-9]%', reverse([Column 1])), 
                                 1000) + 'x'
                             ) - 1
    )
) lastNumericPart
```

[**`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/4708)

Comment: how I do UPDATE?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ';'. For update

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(Column1, 
                 patindex('%[0-9]%', 
                          Column1), 
                 len(Column1) - patindex('%[0-9]%', 
                                         Column1) +1) as Column2
from MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way without a function... regardless of where your numbers are

```
declare @table table (c varchar(256), c2 int default null)
insert into @table
values
('pink dog 306',null),
('black 225 friday',null),
('809 red potato',null)

update @table
set c2 = 
replace(LEFT(SUBSTRING(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(c,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ',''),',',''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(c,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ',''),',','')), 8000),
           PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(c,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ',''),',',''), PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(c,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ',''),',','')), 8000) + 'X') -1),'.','')


select * from @table
```